# Can I filter out JSON information and display it using react?

Tags: reactjs, json, filter, drop-down-menu

I am making a web app with react for ordering food and drinks and the menu is stored in a database, however I want categories as dropdowns and info under the categories with these category tags, now I'm using react bootstrap and won't need help with that but I was just asking if it's possible to filter out information by it's JSON key i.e

```
{
category:"Food"
sub-category: "On The Grill"
item: "Mixed Grill"
price: 16.99
}
```

So i would have the food and drink on separate "tabs" and "On The Grill, to be displayed as a dropdown title, and mixed grill to be displayed under it, is that possible using, .map or .forEach()

Comment: there's no real filtering involved in this case, you simply put the data you want where you want it.

Comment: So if I have a category I can display it and all of the data with that category?

Comment: yes, as in your case they're just object properties. foo.category, foo['sub-category'], foo.item, etc

Comment: alright thank you